# Term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to acquire locks on each element in my matrix for this I write following code:

```
std::map<unsigned int, omp_lock_t> ds_lock;
void Sparse_Matrix_FL::setValue(unsigned int rid, unsigned int cid, double value)
{
    omp_set_lock(&ds_lock(rid,cid));
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator str = data_Matrix[rid].begin();
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator end = data_Matrix[rid].end();

    while (str->first != cid && str != end) str++;
    if (str != end)
        if (value != 0)
            str->second = value;
        else
            data_Matrix[rid].erase(str);
    else
        if (value != 0)
            data_Matrix[rid][cid] = value;
omp_unset_lock(&ds_lock(rid,cid));
}
```

But i got the errors:

> call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or
>   conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

This is another error.

> term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

I can't understand where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Which line is the error on? I assume `omp_set_lock(&ds_lock(rid,cid));` What exactly are you trying to do here? `ds_lock` is a map, did you want `&(ds_lock[<int>])` to get the value from the map and use its address?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes its on set lock. I want to acquire on lock every location in sparse matrix.

Comment: What does &ds_lock(rid,cid) mean? Isin't ds_lock a map? You are not using it correctly. I presume you that you want to get the lock on each row and column mapping. But your map is a mapping from an unsigned int to a lock. How do you expect to mention a row and a column id just using one unsigned int?

Comment: @MSSrikkanth so I need to get two unsigned int?

Comment: @MSSrikkanth `&ds_lock` means lock the column 1 of row 1. Please tell me how to use it correctly

Comment: Probably your map can be defined as std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, omp_lock_t*> ds_lock; And you have to use it like omp_set_lock(ds_lock[make_pair(rid,cid)]). I am not familiar with this omp_lock_t...so not sure if storing a pointer (or a unique_ptr or shared_ptr to it) is the right way to do it. But what you are doing is clearly wrong.

Comment: @MSSrikkanth used your approach it says `make_pair` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up `std::map` elements either through the subscript operator `[]` or using the `find` method. `std::map` is not callable so you can't use the `ds_lock(rid,cid)` syntax.

You map needs to use `std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int >` as its key type.

You would then be able to lock using `omp_set_lock(&ds_lock[std::make_pair(rid,cid)]);`

However you will need to make sure that every used element of the map has been initialised in advance otherwise as `std::map` is not thread safe you will run into issues when the subscript operator automatically creates new elements, you would also need to call `omp_init_lock` on the newly created values.

To ensure that `omp_unset_lock` is always called using the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) pattern would be advisable. A fully working example fixing the above issues could look something like this:

```
class omp_locker
{
  public:
    omp_locker( omp_lock_t& lock )
    : lock( lock )
    {
      omp_set_lock( &lock );
    }
    omp_locker( const omp_locker& ) = delete;
    omp_locker& operator=( const omp_locker& ) = delete;

    ~omp_locker()
    {
      omp_unset_lock( &lock );
    }

  private:
    omp_lock_t& lock;
};

std::map< std::pair< unsigned int, unsigned int >, omp_lock_t> ds_lock;
std::mutex ds_lock_mutex;

omp_lock_t& getLock( unsigned int rid, unsigned int cid )
{
  std::lock_guard lock( ds_lock_mutex );
  auto key = std::make_pair( rid, cid );
  auto it = ds_lock.find( key );
  if ( it == ds_lock.end() )
  {
    it = ds_lock.insert( it, std::make_pair( key, omp_lock_t() ) );
    omp_init_lock( it->second );
  }
  return it->second;
}

void Sparse_Matrix_FL::setValue(unsigned int rid, unsigned int cid, double value)
{
    omp_locker lock( getLock( rid, cid ) );
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator str = data_Matrix[rid].begin();
    std::map<unsigned int, double>::iterator end = data_Matrix[rid].end();

    while (str->first != cid && str != end) str++;
    if (str != end)
        if (value != 0)
            str->second = value;
        else
            data_Matrix[rid].erase(str);
    else
        if (value != 0)
            data_Matrix[rid][cid] = value;
}
```

You'll need to call `omp_destroy_lock` on every element of the `std::map` at the end of your program.